# Spring Security with multiple OAuth2 flows

Tags: spring, kotlin, amazon-cognito

I have some Spring projects with Spring Security, and using AWS Cognito only for authentication.
One of the projects (let's call it `authorities-api`) is in charge of manage user authorities. So I have a custom user introspection endpoint.

This flow is covered by `authentication code` and works well. This is the `SecurityFilterChain` that works right now:

```
@Bean
fun filterChain(httpSecurity: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
    httpSecurity
        .crsf { //omitted code }
        .sessionManagement { //omitted code }
        .authorizeHttpRequests { //omitted code }
        .httpBasic().disable()
        .oauth2ResourceServer { resourceServer ->
            //This works and calls the authorities-api to get user authorities
            resourceServer.opaqueToken { it.introspector(jwtOpaqueTokenIntrospector) } 
        }
        .cors { //omitted code }
}
```

But now I want also to secure the communication between APIs.
I have created an app client into Cognito's user pool, with the `client credentials` flow. I have set the APIs with the following beans creation:

```
@Bean
fun clientRegistration(
    @Value("\${path.to.clientId}") clientId: String,
    @Value("\${path.to.clientSecret}") clientSecret: String,
    @Value("\${path.to.tokenUri}") tokenUri: String,
    @Value("\${path.to.registrationId}") registrationId: String): ClientRegistration {
    return ClientRegistration
        .withRegistrationId(registrationId)
        .tokenUri(tokenUri)
        .clientId(clientId)
        .clientSecret(clientSecret)
        .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
        .build()
}

@Bean
fun clientRegistrationRepository() = InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistration())
```

Also I have the `webClient` configuration:

```
@Bean
fun webClient(
    clientRegistrationRepository: ClientRegistrationRepository,
    @Value("\${path.to.registrationId}") registrationId: String
): WebClient {
    val clientService = InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrationRepository)
    val authorizedClientManager = 
       AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrationRepository, clientService)
    val oauth = ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager)
    oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId(registrationId)
    return WebClient.builder().filter(oauth).build()
}
```

Then, I added the following line to configure the client:

```
@Bean
fun filterChain(httpSecurity: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
    httpSecurity
        .crsf { //omitted code }
        .sessionManagement { //omitted code }
        .authorizeHttpRequests { //omitted code }
        .httpBasic().disable()
        .oauth2Client { it.clientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistrationRepository()) } //this line
        .oauth2ResourceServer { resourceServer ->
            //This works and calls the authorities-api to get user authorities
            resourceServer.opaqueToken { it.introspector(jwtOpaqueTokenIntrospector) } 
        }
        .cors { //omitted code }
}
```

With this beans I thought it would be easier to make Spring understand both flows, but since Cognito only differs the generated access token from `authentication code` to `client credentials` by a few fields (`scope` for client credentials, `redirect uri` for authentication code, for instance), Spring is still making a request to user introspection endpoint, which is not necessary.

How can I have both OAuth2 flows in the same API and make it call user introspection only if the flow is `authorization code`?

Comment: How do you expect the access token of the requests from your programmatic client to be validated if it is not introspected?

Comment: @ch4mp actually I don't. I thought Cognito would validate if there was a client with the credentials. Once its validated, Spring could check with `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('SCOPE_my_custom_scope'")` if the scopes match (ignoring other `hasAuthorties`) and would allow the machine to communicate.

Seems I have not understood the flow correclty. Can you give me some advices?

Comment: A resource server always validates the tokens of the requests it receives. The flow used to get that token is not important. A client does not validate the access token it gets. This token will be checked on the resource server to which the request is sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is pretty messy and let me think you haven't grasped some basic concepts. So lets review the basis.

There is no reason to configure your app as a client for it to accept tokens issued using both `authorization_code` (not `authentication code`) and `client_credentials` flows. It being a resource server is just enough.

Configuring an application as a resource server and also as a client (without `oauth2Login`), like you do, makes sense if all the following conditions are met:

- you want your resource server to **send requests to another resource server**
- you want this requests to be authorized as a programmatic client (if you want to send the request on behalf of the resource owner who initiated the request to your resource server, just forward the token you received)
- you use a REST client which can use Spring Security OAuth2 client configuration (`WebClient`, `RestTemplate` or `@FeignClient`)

But with such a configuration, **your app will not introspect the tokens it gets as client to query other resource servers.** It will only introspect tokens from the requests it receives.

Flows (all of it) are used by **clients** to get tokens from **Authorization-servers**.

**Clients** use this tokens to authorize requests to **resource servers**.

**Resource servers** validate access tokens and get the claims associated with it either by decoding it when it is a JWT (using a public key fetched from the **authorization server** which issued it) or introspecting it on the **authorization server** (whatever the format).

The flow a client used to get a token from the authorization-servers is of no matter to the resource server and doesn't change a thing to the way this resource server validates the token or gets the claims associated with it.

The tokens your app will get with `client_credential` flow to authorize its own requests to another resource server are not the same thing as the tokens it validates: it can be in another format or be issued by another authorization server (it will, for instance, if you need to send requests to Google or Facebook APIs from your resource server).

Comment: I suppose this is the standard overall flow, but in our case, we don't need to validate the access token from client credentials. Once is authenticated, it is enough. So, just by curiosity, is there any way to skip the introspection when is client credentials? I have already a version with introspection after your answer and it works.

Comment: The client, does not validate he gets with client credentials. So, I guess you're talking about the resource server. Again **It has no idea with which flow the token from an incoming request was obtained**. And even if it was included in the request: **1)** maybe it is not what it pretends to be (hacked) **2)** maybe it is not valid anymore **3)** It is considered "opaque" so the claims associated are obtained through introspection.